# How to stop a service in Linux CentOS 7 Elastix-Firstboot.service

Tags: linux

I am having a problem with CentOS 7, whenever it boots it gets stuck at [OK] Started elastix.firstboot.service.. It stays there for about 10 minutes before timing out and moving on. This causes the exceptionally long boot time.

```
[OK] Stopped LSB: Asterisk PBX.
[OK] Started MariaDB database server. 
     Starting elastix-firstboot.service...
[OK] Started elastix-firstboot.service.
[OK] Created slice user-0.slice
```

I want init.d to not start this service at all. However, I have checked the chkconfig --list and I am not able to see this service anywhere.

```
LCDd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
a2b-callback-daemon     0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
asterisk        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
cluster         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
dahdi           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
elastix-portknock       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
elastix-updaterd        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
hylafax         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
iaxmodem        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
iprdump         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
iprinit         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
iprupdate       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
lcdelastix      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
netconsole      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
openfire        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
pf_ring         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
wanrouter       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

I dont know how this service is started. I have also looked at ps -aef command result but I am not able to find anything unusual.

Please help.

Comment: to disable the service during boot, do this: `systemctl disable myservicename`

Comment: Thank youbit worked